# Wordpress Function php not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to customize a WordPress Theme. I have tried to Change the feather Image part (function.php) code like bellow. I change the Width and Height. Changed width work but not work the changed Height. when I Apply "colorskin-medium-thumb" only effect the 800 width (800) but not Height (400). Bellows are default Code.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size('colorskin-large-thumb', 830);
add_image_size('colorskin-medium-thumb', 800, 400, true);
add_image_size('colorskin-small-thumb', 230);
```

Whats the main reason such type of output.

Comment: It depends on the original image dimensions.  If the width of the image is less than 400px wide and you specify 400px crop then it won't be able to make it 400px wide.  You'll get something like 800px x 200px or whatever it originally is for the width.  What are the original image dimensions?

Comment: The original Image size is 800 x 650

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to make custom sizes:

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );

function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'your-custom-size' => __( 'Your Custom Size Name' ),
    ) );
}
```

---

Also the boolean paramater of your existing code means:

$crop
(bool|array) (Optional) Whether to crop images to specified width and height or resize. An array can specify positioning of the crop area.

**Default value: false**